# Android arraylist: Pictures randomizing and not matching right description

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, int

please pardon me. I'm new to java and android development, please help me here: This code is to feed images into GridLayout(Worked) and attach the right decscription in String[] to the selected image in the GridLayout. The Problem here is: It mis-matches the images in each grid and randomly matches them to the wrong description details(TextView).      I know the problem is in the Math.random() line. Please my request is for another way or any other suggestion of how I can successfully match the pictures in my int[] to the corresponding texts in string[]........please`

```js
package tan.myplay

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class BitmapUtils {
 
    
    int[] mPhotos = {
            R.drawable.p1,
            R.drawable.p2,
            R.drawable.p3,
            R.drawable.p4,
            R.drawable.two_of_cairo_museum_looted_artefacts_found_in_garden,
               };
    int numb = mPhotos.length;
    
    
    
    
    
    String[] mDescriptions = {
      " 18th dynasty monarch, better known as King Tut, ruled in the 13th century BC. ",
                      
            "2. I took this shot with a pinhole camera ",
               
            "3. I don't remember where or when I took t",
            
            "4. Right the detritus of mankind.",
    };

    static HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> sBitmapResourceMap = new HashMap<Integer, Bitmap>();

   
    
    
    public ArrayList<PictureData> loadPhotos(Resources resources) {
        ArrayList<PictureData> pictures = new ArrayList<PictureData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numb; ++i) {
            int resourceId = mPhotos[(int) (Math.random() * mPhotos.length)];
            Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(resources, resourceId);
            Bitmap thumbnail = getThumbnail(bitmap, 200);
            String description = mDescriptions[(int) (Math.random() * mDescriptions.length)];
            pictures.add(new PictureData(resourceId, description, thumbnail));
        }
        return pictures;
    }_
```

`

Comment: You have 4 descriptions for 5 photos, how is it supposed to match up?

Comment: Create an array of **bitmap** instead of int

Comment: @IsaacROyewole Is there some reason that you are doing this --> `(Math.random() * mPhotos.length)` and this --> `(Math.random() * mDescriptions.length)`?

Comment: @iRuth , No. Please pardon me. I have tried (mPhotos.length==mDescription.length) and (Math.abs())......I know I am not yet getting something right. Please help me with any suggestion you might have......just to attach the mDescription to the corresponding mPhotos

Comment: @IsaacR.Oyewole What do you want to accomplish?